# How to create multiple packages in npm?

Tags: npm

I have one package in npm. I want to create another package, but I don't see any option. Am I missing something?

I have searched my account and organisation account in npm. npmjs.com/settings/xxx/packages. I don't see any option.

I have tried to publish the package, But I got "You do not have permission to publish "xx-xx-xx". Are you logged in as the correct user?" error.

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have searched my account and organisation account in npm. https://www.npmjs.com/settings/xxx/packages. I don't see any option. I have tried to publish the package, But I got "You do not have permission to publish "xx-xx-xx". Are you logged in as the correct user?" error.

Answer (score 3):

I think I found the answer. npm publish will actually create a package for you and package name has to be unique. The package name I was trying was already exist and that's why I was getting unauthorized error. Thanks anyway!